# Notice for self-handled suggested edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits

After accepting a [suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/53404) for my post, the following message was shown:

> This suggested edit to your post has already been handled and your action is no longer required.

> [image: Suggested edit]

Is it normal to show that message in case of an edit approved by the post's owner?

**Note**: In this case, the end of the current sentence (i.e. "your action is no longer required") is slightly confusing, since an action was done already (approve edit). But maybe my point of view is wrong?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to show it?

Comment: @Servy I think in this case current sentence i.e. end of it "your action is no longer requested" is slightly confuses me. Because I already did some action (approve edit). May be my point of view is wrong.

Comment: @alexolut Is an action **still** being requested of the user?  If so, then it's wrong, and shouldn't be posted.  If no, then the message is correct, there is no *further* action being requested, and it's entirely appropriate for it to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

**The dev team didn't consider it as a bug or an issue**

This is already discussed between me and Oded [in this chat room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/the-new-edit-to-reviews) on july 28<sup>th</sup>

The point Oded said was

> It was already handled... doesn't distinguish who handled it (and doesn't really matter much). Your action is indeed no longer required.

and Oded concluded it with this message

> Lets put it this way - is there any real option for people to be confused and not know what to do with this message?
>   **It is essentially - "nothing to do here. move along..."**

Comment: Oh, you just changed the name... I think discussed sentence should also be changed :)

Comment: I bolded some parts, joined 2 messages together but the meaning is not changed. You can read the full transcript in the bookmark (the link in the answer)

Comment: By "sentence" I meant "This suggested edit to your post has already been handled and your action is no longer required."

Comment: I think they won't change it. because it happens rarely that a user visit it again. they may have priorities